# Adding reversed numbers then reversing the sum

Tags: c++, math

I need help with my program. The concept is to accept 2 integers, add their reversed values, then reverse the sum. I have already tried debugging my code but still I can't see what's wrong with it. Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int t, n1, n2;
        cin >> t;

        while(t--)
        {
            int n_digs1=1, n_digs2=1, res1=0, res2=0, f1=0, f2=0;
            cin >> n1 >> n2;
            for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
            {
                if((int)(n1/pow(10,i)) != 0)
                    n_digs1++;
                else
                    f1=1;
                if((int) (n2/pow(10,i)) != 0)
                    n_digs2++;
                else
                    f2=1;
                if(f1==1 && f2==1){
                    //cout << n_digs1 << n_digs2 << endl;
                    break;}
            }
            int rev1, rev2;
            for(int i=n_digs1-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                rev1 = n1%10;
                n1/=10;
                res1 = res1 + rev1*pow(10,i);
            }
            for(int i=n_digs2-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                rev2 = n2%10;
                n2/=10;
                res2 = res2 + rev2*pow(10,i);
            }
            int n3 = res1+res2, n_digs3=1, rev3, res3=0;
            for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
            {
                if((int)(n3/pow(10,i)) != 0)
                    n_digs3++;
                else
                    break;
            }

            for(int i=n_digs3-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                rev3 = n3%10;
                n3/=10;
                res3 = res3 + rev3*pow(10,i);
            }
            cout << res3 << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is based on SPOJ.(http://www.spoj.com/problems/ADDREV/)
Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There seems to be a lot of extra code that isn't needed to understand the question.  Please try to narrow your question down the the [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed to get an answer.

Comment: did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: My first recommendation would be to write a separate function that reverses the digits of a number. Mostly because you have to do it twice, but it would also make it easier to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I agree that you should write a simple function that takes an int, and returns the reversed int.  Then this whole exercise becomes a 5 or 6 line reverse function, and a 5 or 6 line main() program.

Comment: If you do what was suggested, the bulk of the main() program would be this: `cout <<  reverse_num( reverse_num(input1) + reverse_num(input2) );`  So it is a one-line main program.  As to the reverse_num function, that is a trivial function, no more than 5 lines.  Also, those calls to `pow` are totally unnecessary.  Take a step back and think about how to take a number, get the last digit, and move that digit to the left each time you read the next digit.  It is a simple loop, no `pow` involved (but modulus, division, and addition are done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to rethink how to reverse a number.

Basically, what you want to do is to have a running total starting from 0.

Then starting from the rightmost digit in the number to reverse, you

1) Take the total and multiply it by 10.  This "moves" the digits of the running total to the left by 1 place, leaving a 0 in the units place in the total.

2) Retrieve the rightmost digit from the input number you want to reverse, and add it to the total.

3) Divide the input number by 10 and store results back into the input number.  If the result is 0, stop, else go to step 1).

That's it.

So for example, to reverse the number 123:

> 1) Total = 0.
>
> 2) Total = (Total x 10) + (last_digit_of_number) = (0 x 10) + 3 = 3
>
> 3) Divide number by 10  (123 / 10), so number is now 12.
>
> 4) Total = (Total x 10) + (last_digit_of_number) = (3 x 10) + 2 = 32
>
> 5) Divide number by 10  (12 / 10), so number is now 1
>
> 6) Total = (Total x 10) + (last_digit_of_number) = (32 x 10) + 1 = 321
>
> 7) Divide number by 10  (1 / 10), so number is now 0.  We can stop.

So Total is 321, thus the number has been reversed

Look at the code below:

```
unsigned long reverse_num(unsigned long num)
{
    unsigned long sum = 0;  // our running total
    while (num)    // keep going until our input is 0
    {
        sum = sum * 10 // multiply our running total by 10, so as to 
                       // shift it one place to the left
        +
                       // add on the following
        num % 10;      // to get the last digit of our input do a mod(10)

        num /= 10;     // divide by 10 to remove the last digit
    }
    return sum;  // return the result
}
```

So now the requirements are that you want to reverse the input of two reversed numbers.  Simple:

```
unsigned long input1, input2;
cin >> input1 >> input2;
cout << reverse_num(reverse_num(input1) + reverse_num(input2));
```

The call is doing exactly what the assignment stated, literally.  You are reversing the results of the sum of two reversed numbers.

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate your help. I hope to encounter more of your great answers in the future. By the way, I'm still a newbie; so please bear with people like me who want to be as good as people like you. :)

Comment: I did, but it says i need 15 more reputation in order for the upvote to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you should write a function to reverse the number because you have to do it three times.

When you're building up the reversed number, you're multiplying the wrong part and multiplying by the wrong amount.

The first two lines correctly extract the lowest digit:

```
rev1 = n1%10;
n1/=10;
```

So if `n1` started at 1234, it would now be 123 with `rev1` holding the value of 4.

Building the reversed value should look like this:

```
res1 = (res1 * 10) + rev1;
```

You don't need to include `pow` at all because subsequent iterations will scale what's there.  To continue the example, `res1` will now be 4.  On the next iteration, `n1` will be reduced to 12 and `rev1` will be 3.  The last line will do this:

```
res1 = (4 * 10) + 3;
```

resulting in 43.  It has now correctly reversed two digits.  It will continue in this manner to reverse the rest of the number.

It is not necessary to count the number of digits in the original number.  When both `n1` and `rev1` are zero, you have reversed the entire number.

Comment: Your help is pretty much acknowledged! I wish to be as excellent as you experts one day. :)

Answer (score 0):

A separate function to reverse an integer would make the problem simpler

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;    

int reverse(int a)
{
    stringstream sstream;
    while (a != 0)
    {
        int temp = a % 10;
        a /= 10;

        sstream << temp;
    }
    int r;
    sstream >> r;

    return r;
}
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b; //a = 12, b = 34

    int ra = reverse(a);
    int rb = reverse(b);

    int sum = ra + rb;

    int rsum = reverse(sum);

    cout << rsum << endl; //46

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ 'reuse' is the keyword.

1. Reuse existing functions.
2. Reuse your own functions.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int reverse_fast(int val) {
    int result = 0;
    while (val) {
        result = result * 10 + val % 10;
        val = val / 10;
    }
    return result;
}

int reverse(int val) {
    std::string s = std::to_string(val);
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return std::stoi(s);
}

int main()
{
    int t, n1, n2;
    std::cin >> t;

    while (t--) {
        std::cin >> n1 >> n2;
        std::cout << reverse(reverse(n1) + reverse(n2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though this should work, these "online judge tests" have a time out limit, and `reverse`and `to_string` could make the difference between a successful submission or not.  So the sure way to beat the time out (if that is an issue) is to reverse the int "in place" by doing simple addition, multiplication, and mod.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I have inserted reverse_fast function for efficiency.

Comment: 'Reuse'. Got it, bro. :)